# What's the recommended way to operate on C# arrays by multiple indexes?

Tags: c#, arrays

Let's say that I have two arrays:

```
double[] array1 =  new double [] {22.5, 15, 33.7, 42, 17, 7.5, 3.5, 1, 17.5, 7.7, 5}
int[] idx = new int[] { 1, 4, 5, 8};
```

Now I need to generate new array that will have values from `array1`, but only this with indexes matching `idx`. So, in this case it should be:

```
{15, 17, 7.5, 17.5}
```

I'm more experienced in MATLAB and I was expecting that I can do simple:

```
array2=array1[idx];
```

But as far as I found the C# `[]` indexing works only for one element queries. So, what is recommended way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well you could do it "long-hand":

```cs
double[] array2 = new double[idx.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < idx.Length; i++)
{
    array2[i] = array1[idx[i]];
}
```

Or use LINQ:

```cs
double[] array2 = idx.Select(i => array1[i]).ToArray();
```

Both will do the job. There's no "shortcut" available. You could potentially create your own class to do custom indexing if you really wanted to, but I'd just use one of the approaches above.

Comment: Thank you, the LINQ seems to be what I needed. I was considering this long-hand way with explicit loop, but I was curious if there's a smarter way to do this in one-line. And indeed, LINQ does it nice.

Answer (score -1):

You can use LINQ's Enumerable.Where method in combination with the Contains method of the System.Array class to achieve the same functionality.

Comment: `Where` and `Contains` really aren't the LINQ operations you'd want to use here. Why iterate over all of `array1` and then have to check for array containment every time, turning a naturally O(M) operation into O(N * M)?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).